# Android (Phonegap) crash on rotate

Tags: android, cordova

I googled that an activity element needs `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` value for PhoneGap to refresh screen dimensions. But then Eclipse pukes that there is an error: `error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden').`. So what is wrong with my manifest configuration? Here is my whole Android manifest configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.agilitus"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
    />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:testOnly="false">
        <activity
            android:name=".IndexActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see I installed all versions above 3.2
[image: My Android SDK Manager window]

Still getting an error on `As you can see I installed all versions above 3.2`
[image: My manifest file]

Comment: did you installed any sdk version above android 3.2?

Comment: Some versions above 3.2 was installed. Now I'm installing all version above 3.2.

Comment: Not all versions required.. Then error will be something else.

Comment: Updated my post with last results of installing latest Android SDK tools.

Comment: In my the problem was the value: `screenSize`. Without this on ratation, in emulator, everything works fine. Current correct value is like this `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Just copy paste this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.agilitus"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
    />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:testOnly="false">
        <activity
            android:name=".IndexActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please try this, I modify my Answer. 
First you Copy past and then Go to Project --> Clean.. (application) Then again Run ..!

Comment: Still app crashes on rotation. Like I said I think `android:configChanges` needs this value `screenSize` because this fires new screen dimensions on rotation, I think. But due to this error I'cant compile my app because Eclipse fires an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to invert screenSize and keyboardHidden.

screenSize have been [added in SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) version 13. If you try to start your application on Android 3.1 or lower, it can't work because the SDK can't find screenSize value.

By the way, [Phonegap starting guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) recommends this value for configChanges:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
```

Comment: Even I can't compile due to manifest error. I'm trying to compile on Android 4.0.3

Comment: android:minSdkVersion should be at minimum 13, target version is not important if it is not less than minSdkVersion.